# Explain why $\{0,2,4,6\}\le\Bbb Z_8$, $\{1,4\}\le\Bbb Z_5^*$, and $\{1,5,7,11\}\le\Bbb Z_{12}^*.$

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Could someone please explain the examples?

I can see that the first example is using modular addition, where 4+6=2. But I lack the maths background to understand the next two examples, I thought the * symbol mean multiply?

[image]

Comment: $\mathbb Z_n^*$ represents the set of positive integers less than $n$ that are relatively prime with $n$, with multiplication being the group operation.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Shaun I am so bad at maths I would not even know how to describe this, please update accordingly.

Comment: @securityauditor That's unfortunately not acceptable for this site, we expect users to put in a minimum amount of effort to use the site.

Comment: @DonThousand I like your explanation. Would you mind showing me how {1,4} can be multiplications mod 5 with a few simple number examples?

Comment: Try multiplying numbers in $\{1,4\}$. @securityauditor

Comment: @DonThousand 1*4 = 4 mod 5 = 4? Any more combinations? Also, somebody said it's still possible to use addition?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use multiplicative or additive notation in a group; but additive is usually reserved for abelian groups.  You could also use a different symbol altogether.   In this case we of course have the abelian $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Was my number example above correct? My question was whether despite there being a * I could still use addition?

Comment: In fact, $\{1,5,7,11\}=\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{12}$, so the last $\leq$ can be replaced with an equality ($=$).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Since you haven't yet accepted an answer, I presume you're still stuck on this question. Is there anything in the answers so far that you're having problems with?

Answer (score 1):

$\{1,4\}\le\Bbb Z_5^*$ because it meets the subgroup criterion:  it's closed under $x,y\mapsto xy^{-1}$.

Other combinations are $4\cdot4=16\cong1\bmod5$ and $1\cdot1\cong1\bmod5$.

So $4$ has order two.

Comment: 1*4 = 4 mod 5 = 4    is this also correct?

Comment: Someone said I can also use addition, despite the symbol being multiply, how would that work?

Comment: It "works", @securityauditor, because $\{1,4\}$ under multiplication, all taken modulo five, is *isomorphic* to $(\Bbb Z_2, +_2)$; one has to be careful, though, to note that $[1]_5\mapsto [0]_2$ and $[4]_5\mapsto [1]_2$ under the isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to check for closure, an identity, and inverses, since associativity is inherited from each parent group; that they are each subsets is clear. I will demonstrate these properties by means of their Cayley tables.

For $\{0,2,4,6\}\le \Bbb Z_8$, we have

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
+_8 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 6\\
\hline 
0 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 6 \\
2 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 0 \\
4 & 4 & 6 & 0 & 2 \\
6 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 4,
\end{array}$$

from which one can see that the identity is $0$ and $-2=6$, and $-4=4$.

For $\{1,4\}\le\Bbb Z_5^*$, we have

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
\times_5 & 1 & 4 \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 4\\
4 & 4 & 1,
\end{array}$$

from which one can see that the identity is $1$ and $4^{-1}=4$.

For $\{1,5,7,11\}\le\Bbb Z_{12}^*$, we have

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\times_{12} & 1 & 5 & 7 & 11\\
\hline 
1 & 1 & 5 & 7 & 11 \\
5 & 5 & 1 & 11 & 7 \\
7 & 7 & 11 & 1 & 5 \\
11 & 11 & 7 & 5 & 1,
\end{array}$$

from which one can see that $1$ is the identity, $5^{-1}=5, 7^{-1}=7$, and $11^{-1}=11$.

Answer (score 0):

A subset H of a group G, with operation $*$, is a subgroup if:

0) H is closed respect the operation of G, that is: for every $a,b \in H$, holds $a*b\in H$;

1) It's satisfied the associative property.

2) The identity element of G belongs to H.

3) Every element of H has an inverse, that is: for every $a\in H$, exists $b\in H$ such that a*b = 1.

**Warning**: in this definition $*$ is a *generic* operation, it isn't necessarily the usual product of integers.

You can verify those conditions for your examples. I'll write the first to help you.

**$\{0,2,4,6\}$ in $( \mathbb{Z}_8, +)$ is a subgroup because:**

0) Every time we sum two elements of $\{0,2,4,6\}$ we obtain an element of $\{0,2,4,6\}$:

$0+0=0,\hspace{5mm} 0+2=0,\hspace{5mm} 0+4=4,\hspace{5mm} 0+6=0$

$2+0=2,\hspace{5mm} 2+2=4,\hspace{5mm} 2+4=6,\hspace{5mm} 2+6=8=0$

$4+0=4,\hspace{5mm} 4+2=6,\hspace{5mm} 4+4=8=0,\hspace{5mm} 4+6=10=2$

$6+0=6,\hspace{5mm} 6+2=8=0,\hspace{5mm} 6+4=10=2,\hspace{5mm} 6+6=12=4$

1) The associative property is satisfied in every subset: we never need to verify something about this.

2) $0$ is the identity element of $(\mathbb{Z}_8, +)$, and it belongs to $\{0,2,4,6\}$.

3) Every element of $\{0,2,4,6\}$ has an inverse:

$0$ has inverse $0:\hspace{2mm} 0+0=0$

$2$ has inverse $6:\hspace{2mm} 2+6=0$

$4$ has inverse $4:\hspace{2mm} 4+4=0$

$6$ has inverse $2:\hspace{2mm} 6+2=0$

You can do the same checks for the other two examples.

Just remember the definition of $\mathbb{Z}^*_m$ : it's the group formed by:

a) the subset of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ that are coprime with $m$,

b) the operation is the modular product (not + as in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ !).

For examples:

$\mathbb{Z}^*_5 = \{1,2,3,4\}$

$\mathbb{Z}^*_{12} = \{1,5,7,11\}$ ... so here answer to your example is immediate (why?).